# How to determine mysql.connector cursor type?

Tags: python, mysql-connector

What is happening in this python code?
If I execute as shown, it prints "MySQLCursor".
If I comment-out "import hashlib", it prints "CMySQLCursor".
I have some code that imports hashlib and some that does not, but I want to consistently detect the cursor type correctly.

What does the "C" mean and what is its origin?

These are the possible cursor types (with or with the C prefix depending on existence of hashlib):

- CMySQLCursor
- CMySQLCursorBuffered
- CMySQLCursorRaw
- CMySQLCursorBufferedRaw
- CMySQLCursorDict
- CMySQLCursorBufferedDict
- CMySQLCursorNamedTuple
- CMySQLCursorBufferedNamedTuple
- CMySQLCursorPrepared

```
import hashlib
import mysql.connector  

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='myuser', password='mypass', host='myhost', database='myschema')
cursor = db.cursor()

print (type(cursor).__name__)
```

Comment: Why do you need to know the cursor type?

Comment: MySQL Cursor types are listed on this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html (It links to pages with more details on each type.) And here's some info on the subclases: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cursor-subclasses.html

Comment: @Barmar  I am writing a generic function that takes cursor as an argument.  I need to know the type of cursor, so I can process it correctly.

Comment: My guess is that all the `Cxxx` are subclasses of the corresponding `xxx` classes, so if you just check whether it's an instance of the `xxx` class it should be sufficient, you don't need to check for the `Cxxx`.